# How to syntetically create a File Upload event to pass to the onChange handler

Tags: javascript, events, file-upload, dom-events

I have an HTML page with a File Upload element like this:

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload your File</legend>
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="File Upload" accept=".txt"/>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

and a script part like this:

```
<script src="myuploadscript.js"></script> <!-- defines myuploadfunc() -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fileUpload").on("change", myuploadfunc)
    })
</script>
```

For developing the function `myuploadfunc()` I would like it that I don't need to click the *Browse* button and select the file `mytext.txt` to run the function, but rather create a synthetic upload event `uploadfile_event` which I can pass (in the document `ready` function) straight to `myuploadfunc`. Therefor on browser reload the upload functionality would run automatically. :-)

So for development the modified documnet `ready` part would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var uploadfile_event = ... // something specifying the file /path/to/mytext.txt
        myuploadfunc(uploadfile_event)
    })
</script>
```

But how do I create `uploadfile_event`? And in particular how do I specify the custom information of the file to upload with its (client-side) path?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is a way to achieve your demand, checkout the [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem), which is able to access OS's file system without file selection.

As you see, the compatibility of this API is pretty poor since it is not encouraged. You should take it with a grain of salt when using it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! But how do I put this FS API call then into an Event variable?

Comment: No, you don't have to. Since you could extract the content of the file though this FS API, and then upload it directly. For what reason do you have to make up a synthetic Event ?

Comment: Well, beacsue the `onload` function is the one I want to test... Anyway, the whole things looks a bit to hard for this use case...

Comment: You may create another version of your `onload` function, which accepts the content of file as its argument.